# Count the elements of a list based to their type in Scala

Tags: scala

I'd like to get the numbers of each of the fruit, based on their type. Obviously I need to accumulate them in some way but what is the best/cleanest/etc?

```
trait Fruit
case object Apple extends Fruit
case object Pear extends Fruit
case class Orange(variety: String) extends Fruit

val fruits = List(Pear, Apple, Pear, Pear, Apple, Orange("satsuma"), Orange("clementine"))

val numberOfOranges = ???
val numberOfApples = ???
val numberOfPears = ???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` with pattern matching:

```
val counts = fruits.groupBy{
  case Apple => "apple"
  case Pear => "pear"
  case Orange(_) => "orange"
}.map{
  case (key, values) => (key, values.size)
}
```

**EDIT** If you like reflection, and your subtypes don't have type parameters, you can use `fruits.groupBy(_.getClass)` (or `getClass.getSimpleName`, if you want strings).

Comment: I like this solution would something like, but not, this be possible:
val counts = fruits.groupBy{
  case _:T => T
}.map{
  case (key, values) => (key, values.size)
}

Comment: Nope, that won't work. You cannot pattern match on abstract types. You could probably do something with reflection, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count` with a pattern match to do this:

```
val numberOfOranges = fruits.count { case Orange(_) => true
                                     case _ => false }
```

The above will print 2.  Just change the pattern match for your other examples.

Comment: I'd rather only iterate over the list once, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using reflection, although you need to use a pattern match to bring the types in scope.  You can't iterate a list generically and get the types of each individual element.

```
val orangeType = reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[Orange]
val appleType = reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[Apple.type]
val pearType = reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[Pear.type]

def getType[T: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag](obj: T) =
  reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[T]

def typesOf[A](fs: List[A]): List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = {
  fs.map {
    // Use pattern match to reify type
    case v @ Apple => getType(v)
    case v @ Pear => getType(v)
    case v @ Orange(_) => getType(v)
  }
}

val fruitCount = typesOf(fruits).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)

val numberOfOranges = fruitCount(orangeType)
val numberOfApples = fruitCount(appleType)
val numberOfPears = fruitCount(pearType)
```

Honestly, this is just grouping by Scala reflection types rather than something more obvious like strings (or some other primitive type) and quickly becomes overly complicated.  Best long-term coding solution is to just come up with your own enumeration and use that, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getClass` in your `groupBy`:

```
fruits.groupBy(f => f.getClass.getSimpleName).mapValues(_.size)

// result:  Map(Apple$ -> 2, Pear$ -> 3, Orange -> 2)
```

Comment: I like this but the Dollar signs are a bit of a shame :-)

Comment: beware that `mapValues` is lazy, so it will recompute the size of each list every time you ask for it.